# Fubini Theorem apply on measure

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $$f(x) = \mu((-\infty,x]).$$ Show that $$\int (f(x+c)-f(x)) dx = c\mu (\mathbb{R})$$ for any $c>0.$

This is what I attempt :

First, $$f(x+c) - f(x) = \mu ((x, x+c])$$
So $$\int (f(x+c)-f(x)) dx = \int \mu((x, x+c]) dx = \int\int 1_{(x, x+c]} d\mu dx$$
If I apply Fubini's Theorem, then $$\int\int 1_{(x, x+c]} d\mu dx =\int\int 1_{(x, x+c]} dx d\mu = \int c d\mu = c\mu(\mathbb{R}).$$

But I am not sure why $1_{(x, x+c]}$ is jointly-measurable or $(\mu \times m)$-integrable where $m$ is a Lebesgue measure. (Precisely, I am not sure why the assumption for using Fubini's theorem is satisfied)

Comment: Is $\mu$ perhaps a Borel measure? (At least, are Borel sets $\mu$-measurable?)

Comment: @DanielFischer It does not say anything about $\mu$, except it is finite on $\mathbb{R}$. Should I just add the assumption myself ? Do you think it is really impossible with just the given information to apply Fubini ?

Comment: Well. For $f$ to be defined, Borel sets must be $\mu$-measurable. (The $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $(-\infty,x]$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.) Perhaps the author thought the implicit fact was enough. I'd prefer to have such things explicitly stated. Anyway, consider the set $\{ (x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x < t \leqslant x+c\}$. What do you know about that set, and what does it have to do with the question?